# Swipe through Activities as oppose to fragments

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I have an activity that contains 5 different fragments that you could swipe through. I would like to know how I could swipe through 5 different activity classes instead.

Below is the code for swiping through fragments:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private PageAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout);
        initialisePaging();

    }

    private void initialisePaging() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment1.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment2.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment3.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment4.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment5.class.getName()));


        mPagerAdapter = new PageAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        onBackPressed();

    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, MoodActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Why would you do that in the first place?

Comment: Cause initially I had an activity hold 5 fragments, and for various reason I realize it would be best if i were to swipe between 5 activity instead. I would want to replace the fragment activity with 5 activity, and swipe between them.

Comment: My advice is to leave your implementation with 1 Activity holding a viewPager as a root layout and have 5 Fragments as it is now. You can achieve pretty much everything you need this way. Is there anything particular you want to achieve? Probably I can help you with that one, but switching to 5 Activities is an idea I'd never support for your scenario.